# First variable replacing others

Tags: python-3.6

I have the following code:

```
from a3_functions import convert_date

date=int(input('Please enter the date in the format: ddmmyyyy'))

days, months, years=convert_date(date)

print("{0:02d}/{0:02d}/{0:04d}".format(days, months, years))

print(days)

print(months)

print(years)
```

But when I run it outputs the following:

```
Please enter the date in the format: ddmmyyyy03061314
03/03/0003
3
6
1314
```

Why does the sentence form of my output just output the first variable three times? Even though when I print them individually they print their respective values.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to format code in your question to make it more readable.

Comment: if my answer was helpful to you, I would be very happy if you could please mark it as the correct answer. Please just come back with more questions, if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is using positional indices (which all are 0 and thus taking the first element).

Try this format string instead (I basically only removed all the `0` in front of the `:`):

```
>>> print("{:02d}/{:02d}/{:04d}".format(days, months, years))
03/06/1314
```

If you want to keep the positional arguments, you could just increment the numbers like this:

```
>>> print("{0:02d}/{1:02d}/{2:04d}".format(days, months, years))
03/06/1314
```

Alternatively, you could also name the positions to use an even more readable format string:

```
>>> print("{day:02d}/{month:02d}/{year:04d}".format(day=days, month=months, year=years))
03/06/1314
```

[PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) has a great overview over the new-style format strings:

> With new style formatting it is possible (and in Python 2.6 even
>   mandatory) to give placeholders an explicit positional index.
>
> This allows for re-arranging the order of display without changing the
>   arguments.
>
> This operation is not available with old-style formatting.
>
> New: '{1} {0}'.format('one', 'two')
>
> Output: two one